# delete the selected row on the second page does not work

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I managed to implement checked all with checkbox input in jquery DataTable.

Rows selected on the first page can be deleted properly. however the selected rows on the next page cannot be deleted.

I'm confused to continue the code below. any suggestions?

Thank You

```
    let rows = table.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();

    if ($('input:checked', rows).length >= 2) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure ?')) {
                **$.post(url, $('.form-product').serialize())**
                .fail((errors) => {
                    alert('Can't delete data');
                    return;
                });
        }
    } else {
        alert('Select the data to be deleted!');
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to post the code that builds the table please?

Comment: Sorry my friend, I don't understand what you mean.

I'm having trouble deleting data on each selected table row.

When I delete any line in a page, the deletion process runs fine.

However, the main problem is that when I select a row on each page of a different datatable, the deletion process is successful only on the displayed DOM.